# Running multiple Python servers on different URL mappings

Tags: apache-http-server, python, webserver

Python allows me to create and run applications on any port of my choosing, but how do I handle several of such apps together so that the end user can differentiate only by URL? Basically, what I want is:

```
Host        Port     Default URL              Expected URL
localhost   5000     http://localhost:5000    http://localhost.com/app1
localhost   6000     http://localhost:6000    http://localhost.com/app2
localhost   7000     http://localhost:7000    http://localhost.com/app2
```

I think this would have been quite easy if I was using Apache2 (virtual hosts, right?) but how can I accomplish this without Apache2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an nginx reverse-proxy.
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Users go to whatever port nginx is running on, and supply a GET location like /app1 or /app2.
nginx will parse the GET location, figure out what app it should go to, and pass the whole request and its headers to the appropriate service running on localhost:[your-apps-port]

Comment: Hmmm, so we're back to using an existing server. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Don't worry, this is quite typical these days - it improves both performance (via caching) and security to run a reverse proxy, and it really helps to have all your network configuration stuff in one place. Its a pain to learn a whole new program's features/buzzwords, but for nginx/squid/etc i would say its well worth it.

Comment: Honestly, I know very little about servers, but your answer has pointed me in the right direction. I just came across a DigitalOcean article that says Apache and Nginx can be set up together! Thanks once again, and if I'm stuck, I'll post another question here. :-)